# Java - need help for java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am writing some basic Java game code and i cant find a fix for my problem.
Here is the code:

[GameWindow.java]

```
package my.project.gop.main;

import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameWindow extends JFrame{

    boolean fse = false;
    int fsm = 0;
    GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];

    public GameWindow(String title, int width, int height) {
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    private void setfullscreen()
    {
        switch(fsm)
        {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("No fullscreen");
            setUndecorated(false);
            break;
        case 1:
            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            setUndecorated(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
            setUndecorated(true);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void setFullscreen(int fsnm)
    {
        fse = true;
        if(fsm <= 2)
        {
            this.fsm = fsnm;
            setfullscreen();
        }else{
            System.err.println("Error: " +fsnm + " is not supported");
        }
    }
}
```

[Main.java]

```
package my.tdl.main;

import my.project.gop.main.GameWindow;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameWindow frame = new GameWindow("TheDLooter", 1280, 720);
        frame.setFullscreen(1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I do get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

    at my.project.gop.main.GameWindow.<init>(GameWindow.java:12)

    at my.tdl.main.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: The problem must be here - `device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];`. You can't assume that array has at least two elements.

Comment: Java arrays start at zero. Try changing one to zero.

Comment: It's obvious as arrays in java start from 0 and compiler clearly states in which line there is the problem. I think it's trivial.

Comment: @c4k3bomb, please can you mark the answer that solved your problem as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is on line 12:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1]
```

Array index start with 0. So if you want the first screen replace 1 by 0.

Answer (score 0):

here `getScreenDevices()[0]` index should be `0` not `1`. Since your array size is 1 and index start with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];
```

If there is only one screen device you should have `[0]` instead of `[1]` because array indexes are zero based.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are zero-indexed, so when you access index 1 of the array returned by `getScreenDevices()`, you're actually accessing the second element of the array, which in this case doesn't exist. You're much safer using the `getDefaultScreenDevice()` method of `GraphicsEnvironment` rather than getting all screen devices as an array if you're only planning on using one display:

```
GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
```

If you were planning to implement multi-monitor views then you would need to implement a check to see whether more than one display is actually present.